# OnClick Listner is not working in If Else statement

Tags: java, onclick

What is wrong with onclick listner? Out come of If Else Statement goes null to next activity. I tried so many such as PutExtra, Bundle Etc. It goes null but the outcome if else statement displays on same activity. Please Let me sort this out..........

```
TextView txtvw;
EditText edtx;
Button bttn;
int number=99999999;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_barurasavings);
    txtvw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    edtx=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextsb);
    bttn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.okkbuttonsb);

    bttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int number=Integer.parseInt(edtx.getText().toString()


            if(number<=10){
                txtvw.setText("আপনি ভুল নাম্বার প্রবেশ করিয়েছেন।");
            }
            else if (number<=99){
                txtvw.setText("সঞ্চয়ী হিসাবের অনলাইন নাম্বারঃ\n 0480 002 0000"+edtx.getText());
            }
            else if(number<=999){
                txtvw.setText("সঞ্চয়ী হিসাবের অনলাইন নাম্বারঃ\n 0480 002 000"+edtx.getText());
            }
            else if(number<=9999){
                txtvw.setText("সঞ্চয়ী হিসাবের অনলাইন নাম্বারঃ\n 0480 002 00"+edtx.getText());

            }
            else{
                txtvw.setText("আপনি ভুল নাম্বার প্রবেশ করিয়েছেন");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: is the code correct? Integer.parseInt(...) isn't closed.

Comment: i think it's just a typo?

Comment: maybe the problem here is not on the onClickListener but on passing the value to the next activity since it displays on same activity but null on the next

Comment: Still: we need a working [mcve]. Beyond that : the primary language here is English, and it simply helps when code is all English too (that is why you want to create such an mcve in the first place instead of dropping your "real" cide).

Comment: Should i comment out parseint?

Comment: what to do now plz?